# ¿MySQL para empezar con SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Apenas estoy empezando con el lenguaje SQL, he ejecutado código simple en openoffice base pero ahora necesito aprender más, no entiendo qué es lo que debo descargar de la página http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ para poder practicar, ¿cuál es la opción a descargar correcta?

Comment: Descarga MySql Comunity server

Comment: En realidad pueden comenzar mucho mas abajo, con SQLite, ya que es un motor liviano y básico, si solo deseas aprender SQL, no necesitarás mas que eso.

Comment: Te recomiendo que si solo quieres aprender SQL uses este link, no tienes que instalar nada, solo aprender lo que es SQL y seguir el tutorial aunque es basico cubre lo necesario para poder iniciar. Algo muy importante a considerar es que dependiendo del gestor de base de datos SQL Server, PostGreSQL y otros, considera el uso de minusculas y mayusculas, ya que por ejemplo el nombre de usuario "panda" y el nombre de usuario "Panda" no son el mismo, sucede igual para nombres de tablas o campos, de la misma manera postgresql usa nombres en minusculas siempre, ya que las mayusculas deben ir entre co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL y MySQL son cosas distintas.
MySQL un sistema gestor de base de datos, este interpreta y ejecuta las consultas realizadas en SQL, así como este hay muchos otros MSSQL Server, ORDBMS de Oracle entre otras, pero esas son las principales.

SQL es el lenguaje que utilizas para crear consultas dentro de uno de estos gestores. SQL se refiere a Lenguaje Estructurado de Consultas, por sus siglas en ingles Structured Query Language. 
Existe un estándar que rige como deben de ser construidas las consultas para que el compilador pueda interpretarlo adecuadamente. Actualmente la versión del estándar es la SQL-92.

Te recomiendo empezar a utilizar preferentemente el gestor de Microsoft (MSSQL Server), para este existe una cantidad de documentación mucho mas extensa y tiene una gran cantidad de usuarios que te pueden ayudar con dudas mas especificas que te vayan surgiendo en el camino del aprendizaje.

Microsoft ofrece de manera gratuita la versión Express ideal para personas que van iniciando en el mundo de las Base de Datos; para poder comenzar necesitas descargar el motor de la BDs y el Manejador.

Aquí te dejo el enlace:

https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Hay *muchos* sistemas de gestión de bases de datos relacionales que puedes usar para aprender. Si has utilizado OpenOffice, creo que es relevante que sepas que el motor de base de datos detrás de OpenOffice Base es HSQL, un motor de bases de datos que (dicen sus autores) es el más apegado a estándares de entre las opciones de fuente abierta. En resumen: Usar OpenOffice como una herramienta de aprendizaje de SQL es una buena opción.

Ahora bien, si quieres aprender a usar un sistema de gestión de bases de datos "grande", MySQL es un buen lugar para empezar. MySQL tiene varias ediciones, pero la que más te conviene (o, al menos, la que es gratis) es **MySQL Community Server**.

Si estás trabajando en Windows, puedes descargar el instalador de MySQL, que te ayudará a instalar todo lo necesario para tener un servidor de MySQL listo para funcionar. Como mínimo, te recomiendo que instales el servidor de base de datos y MySQL Workbench (que te servirá de interfaz gráfica para trabajar, a no ser que quieras trabajar sólo en la consola de MySQL).

Si estás en Mac, deberás descargar por una parte el servidor de MySQL y después MySQL Workbench. Descarga los archivos DMG.

Si estás trabajando en Linux, es muy probable que puedas instalar MySQL directamente de los repositorios de tu distribución. Por ejemplo, en Debian, para instalar el servidor de MySQL y el Workbench necesitarás ejecutar las siguientes instrucciones en la terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 1):

para agregar algo mas de información a la respuesta de Martín ya que te estas iniciando en SQL puedes entrar a codeacademy

https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql

Que es un curso interactivo introductorio y un buen punto de partida para quienes se inician en SQL.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría que sí, que utilices MySQL para aprender el lenguaje SQL. Hay un libro excelente que te hará avanzar de cero a intermedio rápidamente, se llama "MySQL Crashcourse" de Ben Forta, es corto, conciso y muy completo. Yo aprendí SQL con este libro solamente, es el mejor que puedes encontrar para principiantes. Olvídate de tutoriales en internet que lo que hacen es confundirte más y con seguridad no te confíes en las ayudas de Microsoft que no son nada amigables para principiantes.

Para descargar MySQL y empezar a trabajar rápidamente sin mucha complicación, solo descarga Wampserver que te trae el PhphMyAdmin, en donde puedes practicar tus consultas de manera sencilla sin tanta configuración.

Estas son las vías y herramientas que yo he utilizado para aprender MySQL y yo no soy ingeniero, soy historiador, por lo tanto podrás ver que son las vías más adaptadas a absolutos principiantes.

Answer (score 0):

Debes descargar **Mysql Community Server** y si quieres **Mysql Workbench tool** esta ultima herramienta es una interfaz gráfica para visualizar y diseñar tablas, es  bueno empezar a aprender con Mysql es muy popular en especial en desarrollo web,pero todo depende, así que debes tener claras tus metas y con que  **Stack** quieres trabajar, por ejemplo si quieres trabajar con .Net entonces utiliza Microsoft Sql Server, otras como PostgreSQL,ORACLE son también muy buenas y puedes hacer cosas muy avanzadas.

Nota: No te recomiendo utilizar SQlite como alternativa para las antes mencionadas pues no es el propósito con el que fue creada, **SQLITE** compite con **fopen()**.

Si estas también aprendiendo algún lenguaje de programación o framework de los mencionados mas adelante te recomiendo lo siguiente:

- con **PHP y sus Frameworks** recomiendo **Mysql**.
- con **Python/Django** recomiendo **PostgreSQl**.
- con **C#/.NET/Asp Core** recomiendo **Microsoft Sql Server**.
- con **Ruby/Rails** recomiendo **PostgreSQL/Mysql**.
- con **Java** yo he tenido la oportunidad de conectar con  **Mysql** y
  todo fue excelente.